# What is the conjugate of $[i + e^{iπt}]$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

What is the conjugate of the following complex number?

$$ Z(t) = i + e^{iπt} $$

Is it $Z(t) = i - e^{iπt}$ or $Z(t) = i - e^{-iπt}$? 
 $t\in [0,1]$

Comment: What is $I$? Conjugate of $e^{i\pi t}$ is $e^{-i\pi t}$ if $t$ is real.

Comment: here t is,`t ∈ [ 0,1]`

Comment: Sorry, there ' I ' was a mistake. it should be ' i ' (simple I)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$Z(t) = i + \cos(\pi t) + i\sin(\pi t)$$
$$Z(t) = \cos(\pi t) + i(1 + \sin(\pi t))$$

$$conjugate (Z(t)) = \bar{Z}(t) = \cos(\pi t) - i(1 + \sin(\pi t))$$

$$\bar{Z}(t) = -i +  \cos(-\pi t) + \sin(-\pi t))$$
$$\bar{Z}(t) = -i +  e^{-i\pi t}$$

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that $t$ is real.

If $I$ is real,then

$ \overline{z(t)}=I+e^{-i \pi t}.$

If $I$ is not real,then

$ \overline{z(t)}=\overline{I}+e^{-i \pi t}.$

Comment: there I should be i 
#simple i ( i is complex)
sorry it was my mistake

Comment: Then we have $\overline{z(t)}=-i+e^{-i \pi t}.$